# how do i update state in react for updating the value of an object inside an array using array.map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, state

the function handleFeetAndInch updates the state using index while using array.map and passing the function which updates the state but the state which is mapped is referenced for all the function calls being invoked so the other map indexes dont get the updated state values, are there any practices around this or another way to convert value based on cases the measurement object has the properties as follows:
state = {measurements:[{name:'',value:'',algo:''}...]

```
handleFeetandInch = (key, nameValue, value) => {
  let realFeet = (value * 0.3937) / 12;
  let feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
  let inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
  let updatedValue = `${feet}'${inches}"`;
  const newMeasurement = [...this.state.measurements];
  newMeasurement[key] = {
    name: nameValue,
    value: updatedValue
  };
  this.setState({
    measurements: newMeasurement
  });
};

handleUnitChange = () => {
  if (this.state.isCm) {
    // reset State
  } else {
    this.state.measurements.map((measurement, key) =>
      measurement.algo === 1
        ? this.handleFeetandInch(key, measurement.name, measurement.value)
        : this.handleInches(key, measurement.name, measurement.value)
    );
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isCm: !prevState.isCm
    }));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using the map function correctly. [`array::map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array, the values of the original array mapped to new values.

Update `handleFeeAndInch` simply be the map callback, returning a new value into a new array, **then** set state with *that* array.

```
handleFeetandInch = (key, nameValue, value) => {
  let realFeet = (value * 0.3937) / 12;
  let feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
  let inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
  let updatedValue = `${feet}'${inches}"`;

  // return new measurement value
  return {
    name: nameValue,
    value: updatedValue
  };
};

handleUnitChange = () => {
  if (this.state.isCm) {
    // reset State
  } else {
    // get array of new measurements
    const newMeasurements = this.state.measurements.map((measurement, key) =>
      measurement.algo === 1
        ? this.handleFeetandInch(key, measurement.name, measurement.value)
        : this.handleInches(key, measurement.name, measurement.value)
    );
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      measurements: newMeasurements
    }));
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isCm: !prevState.isCm
    }));
  }
};
```